# Setting up CruiseControl.NET

Tags: c#, cruisecontrol.net

I'm trying to set up CruiseControl.NET (1.6)

The installation completes successfully, however i cannot seem to start the actual service.

When running the CCNET.exe i get a console window that the last thing it writes is: Initialising Security.

Running the service from service control manager also does not work..

Trying to access localhost/ccnet returns no response.

What am i missing here? I have installed the product in the past with success, not sure what is wrong this time.

Comment: I am a previous user of cruisecontrol but switched to http://jenkins-ci.org/ since it is easier to maintain. Maybe you should have a look at it.

Comment: @schoetbi - it is easier to setup, we're using it in my current shop. However, I think that the build information layout of cc.net is orders of magnitude better than hudson/jenkins. Second, as a .net developer, I prefer a .net tool over a java one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@lysergic-acid - Even if the main config is done (server/ccnet.config) and you are running it from a command prompt, you won't see the web dashboard yet.

If you are installing on *IIS7*, the setup process for the web dashboard requires steps that aren't in the *CC.Net* webdashboard setup docs in sourceforge.

What got me working was this *CC.Net* web dashboard installer page, which is from the Confluence site, rather than the source forge site:  http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Installing+the+Web+Dashboard

In the comments area, there are specifics about *IIS7* (I'm assuming that's part of the problem).

I am still having trouble with the service, so I can't help you there, but you can definitely run the web dashboard without the service as long as the cmd prompt version is running.

Answer (score 2):

The setup of the virtual directory for the web front-end might of not completed successfully. Try using the IIS Service Manager to create an application around the Service folder. I think there's an issue with the install if you forget to unblock the download, but I haven't fiddled with it enough to be sure.

Keep in mind that the web front-end and ccnet service are two totally isolated pieces. You should be able to see the web front-end even if the ccnet service doesn't run.

Comment: What is the difference between the 2? can i basically achieve everything without the web front end? do i need to run the service?

Comment: @liortal - The idea behind the split is that you can run multiple CI servers, but have one "monitoring station" via the web front end. For a small scale environment, you run both on the same box. From your description, it sounded like you were having problems with both pieces. The web front-end sounds like a simple configuration issue.

Comment: I am yet failing to actually work with it, nor failing to find decent documentation on the web. It seems i am able to manually create a ccnet.config and invoke ccnet.exe to actually run it, but i am not sure this is the way to work with CCNET. shouldn't it be running in the backgorund? and how to set up the web dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble one time when installing it and IIS was set to disabled (and thus was not running), I had to uninstall CruiseControl.NET, start IIS and then reinstall CC.Net.

Do you have a firewall that blocks ports? The default port is 21234.

You need both the web part and the service part installed to be able to run CC.Net.

Comment: How do i manually add it to IIS? i already reinstalled CC.NET after enabling IIS.